# P2V conversion with VMM to a USB Drive

Tags: hyper-v, usb, scvmm

For testing purpose, I would like to be able to do  P2V conversion thanks to VMM by creating the VM on a USB Hard Drive. VMM (I guess due to Hyper-V) does not show my USB Hard Drive in the hard drive list. It only shows me the physical hard drives.

Is there a way to to this conversion with a USB hard drive ?

I'm on Windows 2008 SP2.

Thanks for your help,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot specify the destination path for one disk within the SCVMM Admin (graphic) console. But :

- You should be able to choose the destination for all files (VHDs + VM Configuration file), and use an USB-connected hard drive
- You should be able to personnalize the process, and the path destination of the VHDs through a powershell script (see NEW-P2V cmdlet)

Answer (score 0):

Hyper-V does not support USB Hard drive attachments. But, can you clarify your scenario ? Are you trying to convert an Hyper-V server ?

Comment: no a P2V, I want to convert a physical Windows Server to a Virtual Machine hosted on Hyper-V (on another server). The hard drive on the physical machine is big so I would like to plug a USB Drive on the Hyper-V machine to store the virtual machine (the result of the conversion).

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using some sort of local or more reliable storage, if you don't have the disk capacity for the VM are you planning to run it off the USB drive?